# I am trying to log the author name and the quote from the JSON file, but the code is not working?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to log into the console the quoteAuthor and quoteText from the data array object, but it's not working Can someone help me, why this code is not working?

```
const showJokes = () => {

  return fetch("https://quote-garden.herokuapp.com/api/v3/quotes")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      data.data.forEach(message => {
        let author = message.quoteAuthor;
        let quote = message.quoteText;
        return showAllJokes(`${author} - ${quote}`)
      })
    });

}

function showAllJokes(fullName) {
  console.log(fullName);
}
```

[json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQqh0.jpg)

Comment: Is it logging anything?

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: Do you get errors?

Comment: It is not logging anything for me, what could be the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only see `functions` declaration in your provided snippet, perhaps you did forgot to call your `showJokes` function?

```js
const showJokes = () => {
  return fetch("https://quote-garden.herokuapp.com/api/v3/quotes")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      data.data.forEach(message => {
        let author = message.quoteAuthor;
        let quote = message.quoteText;
        return showAllJokes(`${author} - ${quote}`)
      })
    });

}

function showAllJokes(fullName) {
  console.log(fullName);
}

showJokes() // <- Add this line
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitri, you are right, I forgot to showJokes function. Thanks for the help